# JSON Object with String Property passed via Web Method to C# class with corresponding Int Property Conversion/Set Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am passing a JSON object to an ASP.NET Web Method where the Web Method takes the class as a parameter. The class has an int property and the problem is that if the client does not enter a value, it gets passed to the server as an empty string and the Web Server fails to handle it properly. I have tried using `int.TryParse(value.ToString().Trim(), out temp);` but I am still getting the following error `is not valid value for Int32.`. So my question is, how can I set the int property to a default value of 0 when an empty string is passed to it? Do I have to change the property to a string?

Client side JSON Object

```
{ q: { "Quantity": "" } }
```

Server Side Web Method

```
[WebMethod]
public ResponseType MethodName(MyClass q)
{
    return Something();
}
```

C# Class

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int _Quantity = 0;
    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return _Quantity; }
        set
        {
            int temp = 0;
            int.TryParse(value.ToString().Trim(), out temp);
            _Quantity = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

As always, any help is appreciated!

---

Update

I changed my class so that the property is a `string` but on the `get` the string is parsed to an int and then converted back to a `string`. It works, but is this the most efficient way to do so?

C# Class

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _Quantity = string.Empty;
    public string Quantity
    {
        get
        {
            int temp = 0;
            int.TryParse(_Quantity, out temp);
            return temp.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            _Quantity = value.ToString().Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to parse this JSON object: { q: { "Quantity": 100 } }, without the quotes and check if the integer property is bound.

Comment: Parse the JSON object on the client side? I prefer not to do this because I feel that I would lose some flexibility with the functionality; i.e. passing the raw data to the server and then having the server handle conversion / error handling with data passed. Do you agree / see my point?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear. How are you generating the "{ q: { "Quantity": "100" } }" object? Post the client side code please.

Comment: I iterate over `input`s with a `jQuery.each();` and create a JSON object. I then use `JSON.stringify();` before sending it to the sever.

Comment: Are you setting the contentType or dataType of your post? ($.ajax, $.post)? Example: contentType: 'application/json', dataType: 'json',

Comment: I am using `$.ajax({ contentType: "Application/json charset=utf-8", dataType: "json", type: "POST"} )`

Comment: Tell me about your environment. What version of ASP.NET MVC are you using?
Try to remove the JSON.stringify function. If you reproduce a JSON object { "Quantity": 100 }, the binding must work.

Answer (score 0):

Your model doesn't seem to reflect the JSON you have shown. You could use a nullable integer:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public QuantityModel Q { get; set; }
}

public class QuantityModel
{
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[WebMethod]
public ResponseType MethodName(MyClass q)
{
    return Something();
}
```

This isn't an exact match to your JSON, because in there the Quantity is a string, but the JavaScriptSerializer will work if you pass valid integer for it. Obviously if you pass invalid value it will crash, like `{ q: { "Quantity": "foo_bar" } }`.

Comment: My model does reflect the JSON object that I have shown. I have used that model elsewhere within my application without a problem. As far as I can tell, this is needed so that when you send the JSON object to the server, it get set to a specific variable (q).

Comment: If you are using jQuery you don't need it.

Comment: I remember trying without it in the past and it did not work. I wonder if it has anything to do with me using ASP.NET 2.0.